# SQL Server : error in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers

I am getting the following error while trying to create a trigger on a table which sends an email to me:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Basically what I have done is:

```
set @stu = (select name, year, gender from studentinformation where id = @id)
set @bod = ' Details changed for ' + @stu

Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @body = @bod;
```

I have just shown that part of code which I think would be having issue. I feel putting brackets is making SQL feel it's a subquery? Is that the reason? But then how do I send results of a query through a trigger via email? The select statement refers to another table not the one on which the trigger is based

Answer (score 0):

you should specify your query in the `@query` parameter of `sp_send_dbmail`

```
exec sp_send_dbmail 
     @query = 'select name,year,gender from studentinformation where id = 1234',
     ...  -- some other parameters
```

please refer to the documentation on sp_send_dbmail for further details
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 value in @stu.  You're trying to populate it with name, year and gender.
I suggest DECLARE for your other values, so somethign like

```
DECLARE @stu varchar(100)
DECLARE @MyYear INT
DECLARE @MyGender varchar(10)
set @stu = (select name from studentinformation where id=@id)
set @MyYear = (select Year from studentinformation where id = @id)
set @MyGender = (select gender from studentinformation where id = @id)
```

Comment: Or a lot easier: `SELECT @stu = name, @MyYear = Year, @MyGender = gender FROM studentinformation WHERE id = @id`- no need to query that table **three times** to get the three values ....

Comment: I am getting an error now which says current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction. The statement has been terminated.  I use try and catch in my trigger